# Battery status stuck at 15% for 2-3 hours, then jumps to 33% after a reboot

Tags: battery-life, battery

I charge my phone running Android 4.1.2 at night, wake up in the morning, pull it off the charger, about 9-10 PM it drops to about 15%. It will sit at 15% for 2-3 hours without losing a single percent, so I thought why not reboot my phone, and what happened shocked me. I expected it to suddenly be at 1-5% after reboot, but it wasn't, tonight it was at 33%. It went from 15% to 33% after a reboot.

I have tried letting it run all the way down then charging it completely back up to 100% and this seems to have no effect.

This isn't really a big issue, but I just wanted to know if this is normal behavior or a software bug? Does anyone know of any way to possibly make the indicator more accurate?

Answer (score 0):

If you are rooted, you can try this.

1. In CWM recovery, Advance -> Wipe battery stats
2. Reboot and drain the battery fully
3. Recharge the battery 100% without any interruption

Answer (score 0):

If you are rooted, wipe battery stats by using the battery calibration app on Play Store. If not, then I suggest taking it to the device center because it looks like your phone's battery has got old and lost its retaining power/actual capacity has been reduced. Or it may be a ROM issue, I can't tell because you didn't mention the manufacturer's name.